# What is the source for this Goering quote on radar?

Tags: world-war-two, technology, quotes

On page 194 of Jonathan Trigg's [The Defeat of the Luftwaffe](https://books.google.com/books?id=mU8dDAAAQBAJ), he claims [Hermann Goering said](https://books.google.com.ph/books?redir_esc=y&id=mU8dDAAAQBAJ&q=194#v=snippet&q=imposing&f=false):

> I have frequently taken a look inside such sets. It does not look all that imposing, just some wires and a few other bits and pieces. The whole apparatus is remarkably primitive.

Unfortunately, the alleged quote is *not* referenced. Does anybody know where it comes from?

Comment: You have used an unusual spelling Just to be sure: are you referring to [Hermann Goering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_G%C3%B6ring)?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens yes, of course, my bad

Comment: Goering would not have appeared on radar, he is too small.

Comment: Do you mean radar or radio?

Comment: @AllnOne according to Trigg's book the comment was in the context of radar.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This quote also appears in David irving's *The Rise and fall of the Luftwaffe*. His reference is footnote 12:

> 12. Ibid., pp. 5482 and 5473. Cf Milch’s report on Göring, 17 May 1947: ‘Almost proudly he boasted to anybody he met that he was so
>       untechnically minded that he did not know how to switch on his radio
>       set; one of his servants had to do it for him.’

The *Ibid* refers back to another footnote

> 6. Messerschmitt: memo on industrial conf with Reichsmarschall at
>      Karinhall (FD.4355/45, vol. 2). And especially Göring conf, 18 Mar
>      1943, stenogram (MD:62, pp. 546Iff). Those present included Göring,
>      Milch, Martini, Dornier, Rottgardt, Plendl, Lüschen, Hertel, Heinkel,
>      Messerschmitt, Franke, Kammhuber, Peltz and Nallinger. Cf diary, 18
>      Mar 1943: ‘At Karinhall: the chiefs of development. Major onslaught!’

Comment: The first distinctly reminds me of all the managers 2 decades ago who'd brag about having their secretaries type up all their emails for them; to him it probably sounded like a humblebrag about what a big shot he was, but everyone else only hears "I'm such moron, it causes everyone around me extra work when they could be doing something productive."

Comment: Thank you. As a former radar engineer the way I see it is that if the quote really means what it appears to mean and Goering really said it one can only shake one's head in total disbelief that these people ..., well, you get my point.

Comment: The MD in the reference is the so-called "Milch documents" relating to  Field Marshal Erhard Milch. A [microfilm copy](https://www.iwm.org.uk/collections/item/object/1030012332) of these is held by the Imperial War Museum library in London, and the original files were returned to the Bundesarchiv in Germany.

Comment: @T.E.D.: The man was a brilliant aviator in WW1, when wooden planes held together by wire were the *latest and greatest* technology. I would take some of his claims on "technical illiteracy" with a grain of salt; deliberately self abasing to ease the comfort of his confidants.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens "deliberately self abasing to ease the comfort of his confidants." What evidence do you have for this.  Pretty much every agreeable account on the man was that he was completely inept as a leader and that he was inept in understanding the rapid changes in tech occurring in WWII.  The aces in the recent book "The German Aces Speak" pretty much confirm this.

Comment: On another note, it's sad when we have to use a book by the gutter slime Irving to prove any kind of point.

Comment: @MarkW I know what you mean. I did a search to see whether any other author cited the same source documents, but they all seem to cite Irving. It's a reminder that he was once considered to be a reputable scholar of the period (before he was [called-out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Irving#Libel_suit) for being a Holocaust-denier and Hitler-apologist)

Comment: @MarkW The two books I checked first cited Irving so that's why I ended up using his book. Didn't feel comfortable about it though.... Strange how someone who has shown he can be a capable scholar can have such unscholary (ok, that's putting it mildly) views.